# Secure Web-Client and API in Spring-Security Configuration in one Application

Tags: java, spring-security

I have setup a Spring boot application running in tomcat to be distributed as WAR to server

I have several HTML pages that does work with form security but I am trying to add a API also therefore I am switching to JWT.

My effort is then to combine local client with back end API in one WAR file as I happen to know it is possible with Spring Security

EDIT: My gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.1.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}
....
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'com.auth0:java-jwt:3.8.3'
```

in my SecurityConfiguration.java I have

```java
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                // remove csrf and state in session because in jwt we do not need them
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                // add jwt filters (1. authentication, 2. authorization)
                .addFilter(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new JwtAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), this.userRepository))
                .authorizeRequests()
                // configure access rules
                .antMatchers("/index.html").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/public/management/*").hasRole("MANAGER")
                .antMatchers("/api/public/admin/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
```

EDIT: Added the JwtAuthenticationFilter

```
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    JwtAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    /* Trigger when we issue POST request to /login
    We also need to pass in {"username":"admin", "password":"password"} in the request body
     */
    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response
    ) throws AuthenticationException {

        // Grab credentials and map them to LoginViewModel
        LoginViewModel credentials = null;
        try {
            credentials = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), LoginViewModel.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Create login token
        assert credentials != null;
        System.out.println("Credentials : " + credentials.getUsername() + ":" + credentials.getPassword());
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                credentials.getUsername(),
                credentials.getPassword(),
                new ArrayList<>()
        );

        // Authenticate user

        return authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain,
            Authentication authResult
    ) {
        // Grab principal
        UserPrincipal principal = (UserPrincipal) authResult.getPrincipal();

        // Create JWT Token
        String token = JWT.create()
                .withSubject(principal.getUsername())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATION_TIME))
                .sign(HMAC512(SECRET.getBytes()));
        System.out.println("Token : " + TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
        // Add token in response
        response.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Added JwtAuthorizationFilter

```
public class JwtAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    JwtAuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, UserRepository userRepository) {
        super(authenticationManager);
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain
    ) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // Read the Authorization header, where the JWT token should be
        String header = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);

        // If header does not contain BEARER or is null delegate to Spring impl and exit
        if (header == null || !header.startsWith(TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        // If header is present, try grab user principal from database and perform authorization
        Authentication authentication = getUsernamePasswordAuthentication(request);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        // Continue filter execution
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private Authentication getUsernamePasswordAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING)
                .replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, "");

        // parse the token and validate it
        String userName = JWT.require(HMAC512(SECRET.getBytes()))
                .build()
                .verify(token)
                .getSubject();

        // Search in the DB if we find the user by token subject (username)
        // If so, then grab user details and create spring auth token using username, pass, authorities/roles
        if (userName != null) {
            System.out.println("userName :" + userName);
            User user = userRepository.findByUsername(userName);
            UserPrincipal principal = new UserPrincipal(user);
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userName, null, principal.getAuthorities());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Normally I could just execute the index.html from the browser by running https://localhost:8443/index
It does give me an error

> There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403). Access
>   Denied

HOWEVER if i test it in Postman WITH a Bearer token It serves the page

My question is how to exclude the HTML content from the `JwtAuthenticationFilter` and how to actually do I authorize my HTML content?

My thoughts is to combine `formLogin()` with JWT but I cannot find sample code to teach me.

Please ask any other code part if you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating I found the answer
Thank you @jzheaux for your Input it was instrumental in clarifying what I need to do.

I needed to split the API from the WebClient and have JWT on the Api part but FormLogin on the WebClient part.

It is is probably possible to to combine the two but my experience with coding is not there yet

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say exactly what's going on with so much custom code, but here are some tips based on your explanation.

### Possibility #1

First, your `JwtAuthenticationFilter` or your `JwtAuthorizationFilter` may be expecting too much. Do they try and authentication and authorize the request when there is no bearer token in the request?

A good way to simplify this is to upgrade to Spring Security 5.1+ and use [its bearer token support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2resourceserver):

```java
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/index.html").permitAll()
        ... // other matchers
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
    .oauth2ResourceServer()
        .jwt();
```

It only activates when there is a bearer token present. Also, it disables CSRF for you for requests that contain a bearer token.

You can add `formLogin()`, but it is a bit at odds with `sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS)`. Form login needs a sessioned web application. If you want a username/password client that sends its credentials on every request, then you need `httpBasic()` instead, which you can do like so:

```java
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/index.html").permitAll()
        ... // other matchers
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
    .httpBasic()
        .and()
    .oauth2ResourceServer()
        .jwt();
```

With this setup, `httpBasic` will engage only when using `Authorization: Basic` and `oauth2ResourceServer` will engage only when using `Authorization: Bearer`.

If you really are wanting `formLogin` (a UI where a user can fill out an HTML form), then you don't want the application to be stateless. You can do:

```java
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/index.html").permitAll()
        ... // other matchers
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
    .formLogin()
        .and()
    .oauth2ResourceServer()
        .jwt();
```

### Possibility #2

Or, second, you might say that the URIs for your API are completely separate from your client application.

For example, URIs for your client app all start with `/app`.
And URIs for your API all start with `/api`.

If that's the case, then you can create two instances of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Configuration
@Order(100)
public class AppConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
        http
            .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/app/**")
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/app/index.html").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
             .formLogin();
    }
}

@Configuration
@Order(101)
public class ApiConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
        http
            .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/api/**")
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS)
                .and()
            .addFilter(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(...))
            .addFilter(new JwtAuthorizationFilter(...))
            .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Note that both of these setups acknowledge that you don't want to disable CSRF for your entire application. You want that protection on for the client app.

Comment: Okay Ill try Possibility 2 as it is more understandable for me - Will mark answer if it works, Thanx, Do you want to see the Custome code?